# php code transfer into js

Tags: php, javascript

the javascript code in php is

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
xajax_getCountry('<?php echo $row['mradio_area']?$row['mradio_area']:0 ?>',
<?php echo $row['mradio_country']?$row['mradio_country']:0 ?>,
<?php echo ($row['mradio_rate']==1?1:0); ?>);
</script>
```

I want to put it into the .js file.

How do I change the `<?php echo $row` into js format?

Thanks a lot for any answer!

Comment: where is the javascript in there?

Comment: Please try more details for your question?

Comment: this is the javascript. (I'm also have a little bit confused, but in the php this code is under the "scrpt" tag)

Comment: well there is a xajax_getCountry function as far as the javascript goes but what is it that you are looking to accomplish? Looking at the code it just seems wonky and won't work even if you are passing the php code as a javascript argument. Clarity and details please.

Comment: @Juni, basically this is already some JavaScript code. It's going to output something like `xajax_getCountry(<mradio_area or 0>, <mradio_county or 0>, <1 or 0>);` So try clarify what you are trying to do: what result do you get? And what result do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just don't know what you are doing because there is no javascript at all but if you want to make this as javascript .js file set the headers of this php file using this code

```
header("Content-type: text/javascript");
```

Comment: thanks, I'm editing someone else's code. I was confused because I don't know why it's written in js tag..

Comment: Of course there's some JavaScript. There's a function being called and the parameters are dynamically generated with PHP.

Comment: just remove the <script> tags because if you will set the php headers to javascript there is no need to put <script> tags as the browser see it as an ordinary .js file and not a php file anymore